# std::getline() is not reading last line of input file that has no '\n'

Tags: newline, eof, getline

trying to read/print contents of a file, where the last line does not end with '\n'. Program simply misses that data

```
while ( !readFile.eof() ) {
    string s;
    getline( readFile, s );
    if ( readFile.eof() ) break;
  //operate on data...
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/)

You need to move the `std::getline()` call into the `while` statement directly:

```cpp
string s;
while ( getline( readFile, s ) ) {
  //operate on data...
  cout << s << endl;
}
```

The loop will run until `EOF` is reached and there is no more data to read.  Whether the last line is delimited with a line break or not is *irrelevant*, as `std::getline()` will do the right thing and return the last line's data even if it is not delimited.

So, `std::getline()` actually does return the last line even if it is not delimited, but you are simply ignoring it, because this logic:

```cpp
getline( readFile, s );
if ( readFile.eof() ) break;
//operate on data...
```

Breaks your loop *prematurely* if the last line is not delimited, because `std::getline()` will set `eofbit` on `readFile` when it encounters `EOF` while reading, however `s` will actually contain the last line's data, which you then ignore.

By moving the `std::getline()` directly into the `while` statement, it will then rely on the stream's [`bool` conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), which will return `true` if `eofbit` is set and none of the error flags are set (`failbit` or `badbit`), allowing the loop to process a non-delimited line.  When the next loop iteration then tries to read past `EOF`, `std::getline()` will set `failbit` on the stream, causing the `bool` operator to return `false`, breaking the loop.

[image]

Comment: this method only works if the last line of data includes a '\n'

Comment: @RoccoRuscitti that is not true. If the last line does not have a line break, `std::getline()` will simply read until EOF, set `eofbit` on the stream, and return whatever it read. The stream's `bool` operator returns true when only `eofbit` is set, so the loop will not break on EOF itself. Only when `std::getline()` tries to read past EOF will `failbit` then be set on the stream and the `bool` operator will return false, breaking the loop.

Comment: I would expect that to be true, but the program that I wrote today did not yield that result unless I used a ternary conditional

Comment: @RoccoRuscitti See my comment to your answer about the ternary operator. It doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: I know what happened: I forgot to recompile my .cpp file with the print function when I used your solution before I attempted it again using the ternary operator, so it didn't appear to work, but as you say, the ternary solution is the same solution with a redundancy

Comment: This is horribly counter-intuitive. In order to read up to the end of file, one needs a (implicit) function that returns `true` while `eof` is set. And to top it all of, none of the function names match the equivalent flag names. The designers of this library must have been on drugs or something. Yikes. Sorry for the rant.